# How to check if a checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, unchecked

I know I can use `:checkbox:checked` to get a list or an array whichever you'd like to call it with all the checkboxes which are checked.

But is there a function to get an unchecked list? (like `:checkbox:unchecked` which does not seem a valid function) I don't want to loop through each element using `.is(":checked")`.

Thanks.

Comment: This probably should not have been down-voted without an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
$(':checkbox:not(:checked)')
```

Comment: you can just do `$(':not(:checked)');`

Comment: Actually not.. i tested.. thats not working.. check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JPACx/2/

Comment: right, it is matching everything which does not have a `:checked` attribute http://jsfiddle.net/JPACx/3/ , probably not the expected behavior of jQuery

Comment: @dku.rajkumar if my checkbox id is `checkme` how can I check whether the checkbox is checked.I have changed your answer like '$('#checkme'):not (":checked")` ,its not working

Comment: try $('#checkme').is(":checked") => true/false, or $("#checkme:checkbox:checked").length > 0

Answer (score 1):

you can try this selector,

```
var unchecked_checkboxes = $(".checkbox").not(":checked");
```

i assume your checkboxes have the class "checkbox".